# Integrating Pig with Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I have installed hadoop-2.5.0, pig 0.13.0 and HBase 0.98.6.1 in linux. When trying to run simple pig script, error occurs as

> 2014-10-14 16:01:54,891 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.equals([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Z
>   Details at logfile: /home/labuser/pig_1413279561970.log

Pasted the log below...

### Pig Stack Trace

> ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.equals([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Z
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.equals([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Z
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.(TableName.java:281)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.createTableNameIfNecessary(TableName.java:344)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.valueOf(TableName.java:382)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.(TableName.java:82)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)

It seems that HBase 0.98.6.1 version does not support for pig 0.13.0
So how to make it works? or which version of HBase does support for pig 0.13.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause for this has been identified to be https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6658 where it says the class "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.WritableByteArrayComparable" was renamed.

You may need to re-compile using the HBase profile you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I recompiled and working fine. But i forgot to update the answer. Anyway this is the correct answer i think.